# How to use SharedResource for data annotations within ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have project using ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2.

For localization I used a SharedResource. Within views and controllers it works fine, but not for data annotations within models.

My model:

```
public class MyProfileModel : BaseModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "HomeFirstNameRequired")]
    [StringLengthWithErrorMessage(20)]
    [Display(Name = "HomeFirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

My startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddLocalization();

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
            {
                options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof(SharedResources));
            })
        .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
                               {
                                   DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(DefaultCultureInfo),
                                   SupportedCultures = SupportedCultures,
                                   SupportedUICultures = SupportedCultures
                               });

    ...
}
```

I read that the value of the ErrorMessage can use localization, but it doesn't work. Also I need it for the display name..

Anyone an idea?

Comment: You're adding `AddDataAnnotationsLocalization` twice, and namely, the second time doesn't do so with the factory you used the first time. I've never done this myself, but it's entirely possible and likely even that the second call is overriding the first.

Comment: As the suggestion from Chris, remove the second `AddDataAnnotationsLocalization`, if not work, make sure the namespce for `SharedResource` is `projectnamespace` without `Resources`. Here is a working [demo](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/48903c3c31ac219f201c610e69872a4cc47b0f2e/LocalizationPro/Resources/SharedResource.cs#L6).

Comment: Oh I codet too long, I didn't saw it and yes, I removed the second one and this solved my problem! Thanks!